parameter is not declared error. parameters file is not found. in vivado 2022.1
I am getting this error message in vivado 2022.1 when I run the behavioral simulation:
ERROR: [VRFC 10-2989] 'PIPELINES' is not declared [F:/githubccsds/ccsds123-master/ccsds123-master/project/project.srcs/sim_1/imports/tb/top_tb.v:86]

Parameters in top_tb.v are declared in comp_params.v, but the file is not being read.
Here are the hierarchy, top_tb.v code and comp_params.v code:
top_tb:
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module top_tb;
`include "comp_params.v"
parameter PERIOD = 10;

parameter BUBBLES = 0;

parameter OUT_BUBBLES = 1;

reg clk, aresetn;
reg [PIPELINES*D-1:0] in_tdata;
reg in_tvalid;

wire in_tready;
wire [BUS_WIDTH-1:0] out_tdata;
wire out_tvalid;
wire out_last;
reg out_tready;

ccsds123_top
#(.PIPELINES(PIPELINES),
.ISUNSIGNED(ISUNSIGNED),
.D(D),
.NX(NX),
.NY(NY),
.NZ(NZ),
.P(P),
.R(R),
.OMEGA(OMEGA),
.TINC_LOG(TINC_LOG),
.V_MIN(V_MIN),
.V_MAX(V_MAX),
.UMAX(UMAX),
.COUNTER_SIZE(COUNTER_SIZE),
.INITIAL_COUNT(INITIAL_COUNT),
.KZ_PRIME(KZ_PRIME),
.COL_ORIENTED(COL_ORIENTED),
.REDUCED(REDUCED),
.BUS_WIDTH(BUS_WIDTH))
i_top
(.clk(clk),
.aresetn(aresetn),
.s_axis_tdata(in_tdata),
.s_axis_tvalid(in_tvalid),
.s_axis_tready(in_tready),
.m_axis_tdata(out_tdata),
.m_axis_tvalid(out_tvalid),
.m_axis_tlast(out_last),
.m_axis_tready(out_tready));

always #(PERIOD/2) clk = ~clk;

integer i, iter;
integer in_count;
integer f_in, f_out;
reg[200*8:0] in_filename;
integer stalled_cycles, total_cycles;

initial begin
clk <= 1'b1;
aresetn <= 1'b0;
in_tdata <= 8'b0;
in_tvalid <= 1'b0;

repeat(4) @(posedge clk);
aresetn <= 1'b1;

if (!$value$plusargs("IN_FILENAME=%s", in_filename)) begin
in_filename = "test.bin";
end
f_in = $fopen(in_filename, "rb");

if (f_in == 0) begin
$display("Failed to open input file %s", in_filename);
$finish;
end

for (iter = 0; iter < 2; iter = iter + 1) begin
in_count = 0;
stalled_cycles = 0;
total_cycles = 0;
$display("Starting iteration %0d", iter);
$fseek(f_in, 0, 0);

while (!$feof(f_in) && in_count < $ceil(NX*NY*NZ/$itor(PIPELINES))) begin
total_cycles = total_cycles + 1;
if (in_tready) begin
if ((BUBBLES || $test$plusargs("BUBBLES")) && $urandom % 3 != 0) begin
in_tvalid <= 1'b0;
end else begin
for (i = 0; i < PIPELINES; i = i + 1) begin
in_tdata[i*D +: 8] <= $fgetc(f_in);
in_tdata[i*D + 8 +: 8] <= $fgetc(f_in);
end
in_tvalid <= 1'b1;
in_count = in_count + 1;
end
end else begin
stalled_cycles = stalled_cycles + 1;
end
@(posedge clk);
end
end
while (!(in_tvalid == 1'b1 && in_tready == 1'b1))
@(posedge clk);

$fclose(f_in);

in_tvalid <= 1'b0;
end;

integer stall_cnt;

// Simulate random stalling of output stream
initial begin
while (1) begin
out_tready <= 1'b1;
if (OUT_BUBBLES && $urandom % 40 == 0) begin
out_tready <= 1'b0;
for (stall_cnt = 0; stall_cnt < 20 + ($urandom % 20); stall_cnt = stall_cnt + 1) begin
@(posedge clk);
end
end
@(posedge clk);
end
end

integer byte_idx, j;
integer prev_done;
integer out_cycles, out_tvalid_cycles;
reg [200*8:0] out_filename;
reg [200*8:0] out_dir;

initial begin
if (!$value$plusargs("OUT_DIR=%s", out_dir)) begin
out_dir = ".";
end
for (j = 0; j < 2; j = j + 1) begin
out_cycles = 0;
out_tvalid_cycles = 0;
$sformat(out_filename, "%0s/out_%0d.bin", out_dir, j);
f_out = $fopen(out_filename, "wb");
while (prev_done || (out_tready !== 1'b1 || out_tvalid !== 1'b1 || out_last !== 1'b1)) begin
prev_done = 0;
@(posedge clk);
out_cycles = out_cycles + 1;
if (out_tvalid && out_tready) begin
out_tvalid_cycles = out_tvalid_cycles + 1;
for (byte_idx = 0; byte_idx < BUS_WIDTH/8; byte_idx = byte_idx + 1) begin
$fwrite(f_out, "%c", out_tdata[byte_idx*8+:8]);
end
end
end
prev_done = 1;
$display("Done with iteration %0d", j);
$fclose(f_out);

end
$display("\n********************************************************************************");
$display("Stalled %0d of %0d cycles (%f%%)", stalled_cycles, total_cycles, 100*stalled_cycles / $itor(total_cycles));
$display("Output valid %0d of %0d cycles (%f%%)", out_tvalid_cycles, out_cycles, 100*out_tvalid_cycles / $itor(out_cycles));
$display("********************************************************************************\n");
$finish;
end;
endmodule // top_tb

comp_params:
parameter V_MAX = 3;
parameter KZ_PRIME = 3;
parameter D = 16;
parameter P = 0;
parameter TINC_LOG = 6;
parameter COUNTER_SIZE = 6;
parameter COL_ORIENTED = 1;
parameter LITTLE_ENDIAN = 1;
parameter NX = 50;
parameter NY = 50;
parameter NZ = 50;
parameter R = 64;
parameter UMAX = 18;
parameter OMEGA = 19;
parameter REDUCED = 1;
parameter V_MIN = -1;
parameter INITIAL_COUNT = 1;


Do you mean that if comp_params.v were read, PIPELINES would be declared? How?

First, your parameters such as; PIPELINES, BUS_WIDTH and ISUNSIGNED are not defined anywhere in the code that you have provided. Which is causing the error ERROR: [VRFC 10-2989] 'PIPELINES' is not declared.
Secondly, to include the parameters us have to use make a Verilog Header file *.vh and put all the parameters in it, not a simple verilog file *.v.

Create a verilog Header file comp_params.vh and define your parameters in it:

parameter V_MAX = 3;
parameter KZ_PRIME = 3;
parameter D = 16;
parameter P = 0;
parameter TINC_LOG = 6;
parameter COUNTER_SIZE = 6;
parameter COL_ORIENTED = 1;
parameter LITTLE_ENDIAN = 1;
parameter NX = 50;
parameter NY = 50;
parameter NZ = 50;
parameter R = 64;
parameter UMAX = 18;
parameter OMEGA = 19;
parameter REDUCED = 1;
parameter V_MIN = -1;
parameter INITIAL_COUNT = 1; 
parameter PIPELINES = 10; //Random Value
parameter BUS_WIDTH = 32; //Random Value
parameter ISUNSIGNED = 10;//Random Value



Include your header file comp_params.vh instead of comp_params.v:

module top_tb;

`include "comp_params.vh"
parameter PERIOD = 10;

parameter BUBBLES = 0;
.
.
.


